# (Java Minecraft 1.14.2) How to detect a player changing the direction they are looking in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know this may not be possible, but just for kicks I'm trying to write a datapack which lets you unlock abilities, such as starting a fire or summoning lightning somewhere, *without* any carrots on sticks or spawn eggs or any items. So just an ability they can use, anywhere, anytime.

I know that I could have an invisible slime and horse teleporting around infront of the player, so I could detect a pattern of left and right clicks, but I think that would affect the player's ability to hit mobs and interact with blocks. I'm not looking to mod the game, and I don't want to use clickable chat buttons with /trigger to activate stuff. I think it may be possible to use a pattern of moves in where the player is looking (because rotation is something that can be detected by commands) so for example left right up up could do something, but I've never worked with rotation before so I don't really know how to approach this.

Can any of these methods actually be made to work and other than these methods, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could probably store the `Rotation` tag and do some subtraction stuff, but that's a major commands system, not really a simply Q&A thing.

Comment: Ok so the rotation seems the most promising. I will try that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in a datapack, it uses two functions

## The setup function should be executed once:

```
#tracks horizontal rotation
scoreboard objectives add DM_rotOne dummy

#tracks vertical rotation
scoreboard objectives add DM_rotTwo dummy

#tracks the distance rotated within one tick
scoreboard objectives add DM_distance dummy

#used for maths
scoreboard objectives add DM_placeholder dummy

#hold the values from the previous tick, also used for maths
scoreboard objectives add DM_lastRotOne dummy
scoreboard objectives add DM_lastRotTwo dummy
scoreboard objectives add DM_lastInput dummy

#flags when an input should be registered
scoreboard objectives add DM_registerInput dummy

#tracks the input in what direction the player moved
#is 0 if the player didn't move fast enough
scoreboard objectives add DM_input dummy

#used as timer to know if a new DM_input value should be registered
#and to detect if a player doesn't move for a while
scoreboard objectives add DM_timer dummy

#use these to remember previous inputs, add as many as you need
scoreboard objectives add DM_stepOne dummy
scoreboard objectives add DM_stepTwo dummy
scoreboard objectives add DM_stepThree dummy
scoreboard objectives add DM_stepFour dummy

#add constant values, these should not be changed!
scoreboard objectives add DM_constant dummy
scoreboard players set minusOne DM_constant -1
scoreboard players set noMovement DM_constant 0
scoreboard players set up DM_constant 1
scoreboard players set down DM_constant 2
scoreboard players set right DM_constant 3
scoreboard players set upRight DM_constant 4
scoreboard players set downRight DM_constant 5
scoreboard players set left DM_constant 6
scoreboard players set upLeft DM_constant 7
scoreboard players set downLeft DM_constant 8

#forces 0 as input, can be used together with timerEnabled=0 to break a chain of inputs
scoreboard objectives add DM_forceZero dummy

#A trigger scoreboard objective that can be set to 1, or 0 by each individual player, 
#defaults to 0, confirms inputs in chat for players where it is set to 1
scoreboard objectives add DM_confDirection trigger

#add parameters, these change how the main function operates
scoreboard objectives add DM_parameter dummy

#Defines how fast you have to rotate for it to count as an input
scoreboard players set speedRequired DM_parameter 2500000

#Defines how fast you can maximaly move before it counts as not moving
scoreboard players set maximalRotationWhenNotMoving DM_parameter 1500000

#Defines how long you have to not move before it counts as an "input"
scoreboard players set timerTime DM_parameter 50

#Defines how long you have to not move before you can make a new input
#this is used to prevent multiple inputs when the player only attempts to make one input
scoreboard players set timeBeforeRegisteringNewInput DM_parameter 2

#enables the input for "not moving", set this to 0 to only allow directional inputs
scoreboard players set timerEnabled DM_parameter 1

#disables the detection of diagonal movements when set to 0
scoreboard players set detectDiagonals DM_parameter 1
```

*Note: the `DM_` is for your namespace abbreviation - it's good practice to put one before all scoreboards and tags and such so they don't conflict with someone else's datapack if  a player has more than one installed. Just use the replace function in notepad to change them all to the appropriate letters for your namespace.*

## The main function should be executed every tick:

```
#get player rotation
execute as @a store result score @s DM_rotOne run data get entity @s Rotation[0] 100
execute as @a store result score @s DM_rotTwo run data get entity @s Rotation[1] 100

#error correction right after logging in to the server, may result in one false input per sitting
execute as @a[scores={DM_rotOne=..-1}] run scoreboard players add @s DM_rotOne 36000

#prevent overflow, or underflow, where the rotation jumps from 35999 to 0, or 0 to 35999, because that's how circles work
execute as @a[scores={DM_rotOne=..9000,DM_lastRotOne=27000..}] run scoreboard players remove @s DM_lastRotOne 36000
execute as @a[scores={DM_rotOne=27000..,DM_lastRotOne=..9000}] run scoreboard players add @s DM_lastRotOne 36000

#calculate relative rotation compared to previous tick
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_lastRotOne -= @s DM_rotOne
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_lastRotTwo -= @s DM_rotTwo

#calculate the relative distance rotated (The square of the distance is used)
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_distance = @s DM_lastRotOne
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_distance *= @s DM_lastRotOne
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder = @s DM_lastRotTwo
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder *= @s DM_lastRotTwo
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_distance += @s DM_placeholder

#determine the input
execute as @a run scoreboard players set @s DM_input 0

#determine diagonals, gets the correct result for horizontal and vertical movement if you rotate very precisely
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=1..}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input += up DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotOne=..-1}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input += right DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=..-1}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input += down DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotOne=1..}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input += left DM_constant

#error correction for input, less precision required for up/down
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder = @s DM_lastRotOne
execute as @a if score detectDiagonals DM_parameter matches 1 run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder += @s DM_lastRotOne
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=1..,DM_lastRotOne=1..}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotTwo >= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = up DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=..-1,DM_lastRotOne=..-1}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotTwo <= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = down DM_constant
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder *= minusOne DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=1..,DM_lastRotOne=..-1}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotTwo >= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = up DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=..-1,DM_lastRotOne=1..}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotTwo <= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = down DM_constant

#error correction for input, less precision required for left/right
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder = @s DM_lastRotTwo
execute as @a if score detectDiagonals DM_parameter matches 1 run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder += @s DM_lastRotTwo
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=1..,DM_lastRotOne=1..}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotOne >= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = left DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=..-1,DM_lastRotOne=..-1}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotOne <= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = right DM_constant
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_placeholder *= minusOne DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=1..,DM_lastRotOne=..-1}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotOne <= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = right DM_constant
execute as @a[scores={DM_lastRotTwo=..-1,DM_lastRotOne=1..}] if score @s DM_distance >= speedRequired DM_parameter if score @s DM_lastRotOne >= @s DM_placeholder run scoreboard players operation @s DM_input = left DM_constant

#set DM_registerInput flag if valid input is detected
scoreboard players set @a DM_registerInput 0
execute as @a[scores={DM_input=1..}] if score @s DM_timer > timeBeforeRegisteringNewInput DM_parameter run scoreboard players set @s DM_registerInput 1
execute as @a if score @s DM_input = @s DM_lastInput if score @s DM_timer = repeatedInputTime DM_parameter run scoreboard players set @s DM_registerInput 1

#increase timer
execute as @a if score @s DM_distance <= maximalRotationWhenNotMoving DM_parameter run scoreboard players add @s DM_timer 1
#set timer to 0 if there was an input
execute as @a[scores={DM_input=1..}] run scoreboard players set @s DM_timer 0
#sets the DM_registerInput flag if the timer has reached the value for when "no movement" should be detected
execute as @a if score @s DM_timer = DM_timerTime DM_parameter if score DM_timerEnabled DM_parameter matches 1 run scoreboard players set @s DM_registerInput 1

#remember values for next tick
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_lastRotOne = @s DM_rotOne
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s DM_lastRotTwo = @s DM_rotTwo
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s DM_lastInput = @s DM_input

#forceZero if DM_forceZero has been set (use '/scoreboard players set @a DM_forceZero 1' to set this parameter; it is automatically reset)
execute as @a[scores={DM_forceZero=1}] run scoreboard players set @s DM_input 0
execute as @a[scores={DM_forceZero=1}] run scoreboard players set @s DM_registerInput 1
scoreboard players set @a DM_forceZero 0

#confirms input to players who have the scoreboard 'DM_confDirection' set to 1, can be changed with a trigger command
scoreboard players enable @a DM_confDirection
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = up DM_constant run msg @s I look up
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = left DM_constant run msg @s I look left
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = right DM_constant run msg @s I look right
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = down DM_constant run msg @s I look down
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = upRight DM_constant run msg @s I look upRight
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = upLeft DM_constant run msg @s I look upLeft
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = downRight DM_constant run msg @s I look downRight
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = downLeft DM_constant run msg @s I look downLeft
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1,DM_confDirection=1}] if score @s DM_input = noMovement DM_constant run msg @s I stopped

#Record valid inputs, you can add more steps according to this pattern if you have enough scoreboard objetives
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s DM_stepOne = @s DM_stepTwo
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s DM_stepTwo = @s DM_stepThree
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s DM_stepThree = @s DM_stepFour
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s DM_stepFour = @s DM_input

#Do something if a chain of correct inputs has been made
#for the input chain 'right, left, up, down' you can use this command
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] if score @s DM_stepOne = right DM_constant if score @s DM_stepTwo = left DM_constant if score @s DM_stepThree = up DM_constant if score @s DM_stepFour = down DM_constant run say I activated skill one
#for the input chain 'upLeft, upRight, downLeft, downRight' you can use this command (the DM_parameter 'detectDiagonals' has to be 1 for this to be possible 
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] if score @s DM_stepOne = upLeft DM_constant if score @s DM_stepTwo = upRight DM_constant if score @s DM_stepThree = downLeft DM_constant if score @s DM_stepFour = downRight DM_constant run say I activated skill two
#for the input chain 'left, no movement, left, left' you can use this command (the DM_parameter 'detectDiagonals' has to be 1 for this to be possible 
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] if score @s DM_stepOne = left DM_constant if score @s DM_stepTwo = left DM_constant if score @s DM_stepThree = left DM_constant if score @s DM_stepFour = left DM_constant run say I activated skill three
#To make shorter input chains you would only use the last few steps, ignoring step one.
#This command would be for 'right, right'
execute as @a[scores={DM_registerInput=1}] if score @s DM_stepThree = right DM_constant if score @s DM_stepFour = right DM_constant run say I activated skill four
```

Comment: You can ask about how this works here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95790/discussion-between-mr-bear-and-nik3141

Answer (score 5):

I do not know much about datapacks, but a function like this should work, even in multiplayer. All the commands can go into the same function and the function should be executed every tick.

This setup uses these dummy objectives:

- rotationOne (for y rotation)
- rotationTwo (for x rotation)
- lastRotationOne
- lastRotationTwo
- timer
- looksLeft
- looksRight
- looksUp
- looksDown
- directionChanged
- lastDirection (holds a value based on what kind of rotation the player did last)
- stepOne, stepTwo,... (for "remembering" the last few actions, you can add as many as you want)
- global (for holding parameters)

`rotationOne` bascially devides a ring around the player into sectors (numbered 0-12 if the number in the first command is 0.036), if a player looked into one sector in one tick, and a different one in the next, then that gets registered as looking right, or left. Imidiately after loading the map these values seem to be negative for a while, this problem seems to resolve itself after a few seconds.

`timer` is a timer that is used to detect if the player did NOT rotate for a while

`global` holds the parameters `min`, `max`, `left`, `right`, `up`, `down`, and `timerTime`.
`min` and `max` are used for the sectors, `min` should always be `0`, `max` is the highest value that `rotationOne` can have before rolling over to `0`. This changes if you change the number in the first command. Make sure to keep `max` updated if you decide to change the number in the first command.
`timerTime` is used by the timer and defines how long a player has to stand still until it counts as "not moving". A value of 20 sets the timer to 1 second.
`left`, `right`, `up`, and `down` are values assigned to each direction, I recommend using `1`, `2`, `4`, and `8`. The value for "no movement" will always be `0`

Using these values you would initialize your scoreboards like so:

```
scoreboard objectives add rotationOne dummy
scoreboard objectives add rotationTwo dummy
scoreboard objectives add lastRotationOne dummy
scoreboard objectives add lastRotationTwo dummy
scoreboard objectives add timer dummy
scoreboard objectives add looksLeft dummy
scoreboard objectives add looksRight dummy
scoreboard objectives add looksUp dummy
scoreboard objectives add looksDown dummy
scoreboard objectives add directionChanged dummy
scoreboard objectives add lastDirection dummy
scoreboard objectives add stepOne dummy
scoreboard objectives add stepTwo dummy
scoreboard objectives add stepThree dummy
scoreboard objectives add stepFour dummy
scoreboard objectives add stepFive dummy
scoreboard objectives add stepSix dummy
scoreboard objectives add global dummy

scoreboard players set min global 0
scoreboard players set max global 12
scoreboard players set left global 1
scoreboard players set right global 2
scoreboard players set up global 4
scoreboard players set down global 8
scoreboard players set timerTime global 50 (for 2.5 seconds)
```

In the first two commands you decide the precision, a higher number at the end will require the movements to be more precise, lower numbers will require bigger movements. In the first command that means that there will be more, or less sectors in the ring. *Make sure to set `max` to the correct number if you change the first command*. The first two commands also store the current rotation of each player, which will be used later.

```
execute as @a store result score @s rotationOne run data get entity @s Rotation[0] 0.036
execute as @a store result score @s rotationTwo run data get entity @s Rotation[1] 0.036
```

After that you can run the following commands. You should not have to change anything about them, though they could probably be more efficient.

```
execute as @a unless score @s rotationOne = min global store success score @s looksLeft if score @s lastRotationOne > @s rotationOne
execute as @a if score @s rotationOne = min global store success score @s looksLeft unless score max global = @s lastRotationOne unless score min global = @s lastRotationOne
execute as @a if score @s rotationOne = max global store success score @s looksLeft if score min global = @s lastRotationOne
execute as @a unless score @s rotationOne = max global store success score @s looksRight if score @s lastRotationOne < @s rotationOne
execute as @a if score @s rotationOne = max global store success score @s looksRight unless score min global = @s lastRotationOne unless score max global = @s lastRotationOne
execute as @a if score @s rotationOne = min global store success score @s looksRight if score max global = @s lastRotationOne
execute as @a store success score @s looksUp if score @s lastRotationTwo > @s rotationTwo
execute as @a store success score @s looksDown if score @s lastRotationTwo < @s rotationTwo
execute as @a store success score @s directionChanged unless score @s rotationOne = @s lastRotationOne
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=0}] store success score @s directionChanged unless score @s rotationTwo = @s lastRotationTwo
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s lastRotationOne = @s rotationOne
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s lastRotationTwo = @s rotationTwo
scoreboard players remove @a timer 1
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s timer = timerTime global
execute as @a[scores={timer=..0}] run scoreboard players set @s directionChanged 1
execute as @a[scores={timer=..0}] run scoreboard players operation @s timer = timerTime global
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players set @s lastDirection 0
execute as @a[scores={looksLeft=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s lastDirection = left global
execute as @a[scores={looksRight=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s lastDirection = right global
execute as @a[scores={looksUp=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s lastDirection = up global
execute as @a[scores={looksDown=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s lastDirection = down global
execute as @a if score @s lastDirection = @s stepFive run scoreboard players set @s directionChanged 0
```

To confirm to a player, when a direction has been registered, you would use these commands:

```
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1,looksLeft=1}] run msg @s left
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1,looksRight=1}] run msg @s right
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1,looksUp=1}] run msg @s up
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1,looksDown=1}] run msg @s down    
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1,lastDirection=0}] run msg @s stopped
```

At this point you should decide how many inputs you want to use for your most complicated ability and add as many as you need according to this pattern:

```
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s stepOne = @s stepTwo
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s stepTwo = @s stepThree
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s stepThree = @s stepFour
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s stepFour = @s stepFive
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] run scoreboard players operation @s stepFive = @s lastDirection
```

And finally you get to make the abilities, you basically just make a long command with a lot of `if`s, one for every step that is important for activating that ability. For an ability that should activate after "*left, right, not moving, up, down*" you would use a command like this:

```
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] if score @s stepOne = left global if score @s stepTwo = right global if score @s stepThree matches 0 if score @s stepFour = up global if score @s stepFive = down global run <abilityOne>
```

If you want to add more abilities that are shorter, then you start at a higher step and ignore the first few steps, to make an ability for "*up, down, up*" you can use this command:

```
execute as @a[scores={directionChanged=1}] if score @s stepThree = up global if score @s stepFour = down global if score @s stepFive = up global run <abilityTwo>
```

I used all of these commands in that order in  a long chain of command blocks. I hope you can just copy and paste them into a function file.

Comment: The different parameters in global are players that do not actually exist. To add `min` you would use `/scoreboard players set min global 0`.

Comment: Sorry but at the end of the answer could you summarize what happens in the commands given an example set of mouse movements? And maybe put what values would change in a sort of 'step-through'? The answer was super well thought out and well written I just don't really understand the big picture.

Comment: @Nik3141 is it possible to add comments in a function file? I could write into the code what happens and comment that out. The last two commands are kind of a bit like an example, I am unsure how I can make it clearer without a lot of effort (that I may put in when I have time for it, but I will not have much time for a few days).

Comment: `#hashtag marks a comment`, but I understand it much better now. The global part was confusing me because I haven't used that before, but I've got it now so don't worry about summarizing it more

Comment: So this system detects movement by breaking rotation into sectors and detecting changes in the sector they are in. I assume it would be possible to expand this so if they make a rectangle with their cursor this could be detected? Or if not, could a rectangle made while facing north be detected? And not just rectangles, but could, in theory, any shape that you predefine with stepTen, stepNine, stepEight.. be tracked? Just theoretical,  but I might try that much later on into this project.

Comment: In theory, yes, but there are some limitations. This line `execute as @a if score @s lastDirection = @s stepFive run scoreboard players set @s directionChanged 0` makes something like *left, right, right* impossible, because you cannot have the same thing twice in a row, BUT I figured that may not work very well, so I added that line.

Comment: Obviously the shape has to be made out of "legal" lines though. 50 worked well as the `timerTime`, not moving felt like not moving and I had enough time to pick the next direction to not mess up due to "not moving"

Comment: Ok. So if I removed that line would repeat movements work? Also, where would I put a command to indicate that a direction had been logged, during the movements? Like chatting the direction they just moved to confirm it for them? Finally, what is the purpose of the += in the line `execute as @a if score @s looksDown matches 1 run scoreboard players operation @s lastDirection += down global`? Why not just set it equal?

Comment: Repeat movements would work... Kinda... If you move in the same direction twice in a row it will be logged twice, that also means that ling movements in one direction may be logged twice. It would likely feel very inconsistent to the player. (Feel free to try it though). The += rows add the detected directions to the "lastDirection". It used to work a bit differently and should maybe be renamed to "currentDirection" now. The four lines are basically used to get the direction you moved in into one value (hard to explain, sorry)

Comment: You can probably just copy those lines and change them a little to confirm in what direction a player moved. Or you could make 5 more commands at the end, one for each direction. (Something like `execute as @a if scores @s lastDirection = down global run msg @s "down"` (I cannot test this right now and I'm not sure if `/msg` even exists in Java, but you get the idea...))

Comment: Ok I think I'll stick with no repeat directions and just use the += and figure it out later. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Nik3141 I missed the "why not just set it equal" part and I guess that would actually make more sense. I add them together, because you can have 2 directions simultaneously in theory, like up and left, which then would be added together. The way this currently works makes this somewhat useless, so It may actually make more sense to set it equal, in which case you move up and left, but only one counts to activate the skill.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was trying to figure outifthere was some complicated arithmetic going on which figures out combinations of directions or if it was just 0+n =n.

Comment: It can be combinations of directions, if there was an operator for bitwise comparisons in minecraft, then it would be very useful, but there is no such feature that I'm aware of. I implemented this and hoped I would be able to use it like that somehow though, so that is just a leftover fragment of an earlier idea, basically.

Comment: @Nik3141 What is the `anchored eyes` part supposed to do in the edit?

Comment: Oh sorry that was left over from me trying to use particles to display the direction that the player had just moved. It didn't work and I forgot to remove it when changing to the `say` command.

Comment: I changed it, approved the edit, and did some minor improvements (like changing the `+=` to `=` and using `msg` instead of `say`, which is more multiplayer friendly, due to less spam. Also a known bug: If you move up and left and it gets registered in the same tick, then both directions will get confirmed to the player, but only one direction will actually be registered. And there actually is a reason why I moved the new commands further down, they have to be there, to prevent a direction to be confirmed twice in a row.

Comment: I'm guessing you saw the question I just posted about detecting charged bows: if I were to retexture a bow into a 'wand', what would I need to change in the above function to get it to log movements when the bow is charged and when it is shot (I'll just kill the arrow) it checks the logged movements against known abilities in a separate function? I don't want the timer anymore because they can just release and recharge the bow to start again, so besides that do I need to make any modifications to the main body of commands?

Comment: You can probably just add a command after this one: `execute as @a if score @s lastDirection = @s stepFive run scoreboard players set @s directionChanged 0`. It would look something like `execute as @a[bow is not charged]  set @s directionChanged 0`. You can simply remove all timer related commands to not have a timer, but I would recommend to just modify them so that you get the value 0 whenever the player stops charging the bow, similar to how the timer triggers the `lastDirection` to be 0. That way the player cannot continue a spell after aborting it, unless the spell actually requires it.

Comment: I just realized that would be a little buggy, but it should be possible to fix those bugs. The two suggestions are mutually exclusive in that form. Edit: mutually exclusive are the wrong words...

Comment: Ok thanks. Unfortunately it looks like the bow won't work so I'll probably just leave what you put there until I figure out another solution. Quick question: I'm planning to make an actual release for this datapack and want to credit you with the system for detecting wand movements, so do you have a specific youtube or mc username you want me to use or is "Mr. Bear 
 from Arqade" good?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95790/discussion-between-mr-bear-and-nik3141).